# How to get PID file in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to get location of mysql PID file using API in windows ?

I am trying to get mysql PID file.

I have written code

```
select @@global.pid_file
```

It is working in Linux. But it is not working in Windows. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'pid_file'`

If it doesn't work I guess it just doesn't exist on Windows systems.

Edit:

Actually, after I checked it turns out that this variable is only used on Unix-like systems, so it doesn't exist on Windows.